# Angular check if observable is null in template

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I have an observable defined in my angular component like this.

```js
profiles$!: Observable<Profile[] | undefined>;`
```

I try to check the length of this array in my template like this.

```html
<div *ngIf="(profiles$ | async).length > 0"></div>
```

With this construct I get the error message `Object is possibly 'null' or 'undefined'.` from the typescript compiler which is totally fine. So add a null check to my if condition.

```html
<div *ngIf="(profiles$ | async) && (profiles$ | async).length > 0"></div>
```

I'm still getting the same error that the object is possible null. I guess the compiler dose not recognise the null check. My question is how to do the null check to avoid the error from the typescript compiler.

Comment: You can try just `(profiles$ | async)?.length > 0`. I guess in the second example the compiler can't know that the value has to exist because of `(profiles$ | async)`.

Comment: Yes, that works! Thank you :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

the problem will happen in case the observable return a **null**

```html
<div *ngIf="(profiles$ | async).length > 0"></div>
```

a quick way solve to this problem is to use the safe navigation operator `?`

```html
<div *ngIf="(profiles$ | async)?.length > 0"></div>
```

or you can use ng-container with ngIf in case you want to apply extra check of the return value of the observable

```html
<ng-container *ngIf="(profiles$ | async) as result">
  <div *ngIf="result.length > 0"></div>
</ng-container>
```